# getting null exception while generating report using C# sparkhtmlreport specflow

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

below code I am getting exception.first I am checking anyone help me on this

```
if (stepstatus == null)
{
    switch (steptype.ToString())
    {
        case "Given":
            scenario.CreateNode<Given>(stepName).Pass("passed");
            break;
```

here getting null exception scenario.CreateNode(stepName).Pass("passed");

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: 1. Answer this: what in that line _could possibly_ be null? Hint: 3 things. 2. If you can, start it in a debugger, set a breakpoint and inspect the values of those 3. 2b. If you cannot use a debugger, plaster it with log output, checking which of the 3 possible things are actually null. When you found out, think about how to fix it.

Comment: I think this could be an answerable question, but we need to see more code. Please [edit] your question to include a [repro].

Comment: might as well add in a null check there... check "scenario" and "stepName" first.